# Compressing Notebook Files

Tags: compression

I need to compress and upload a Smart Notebook 10.8 file for uni along with hundreds of other students! Even though the file is only 3.7 MB, I am still having trouble making it smaller. Can you help?

Comment: Hi Kim, welcoem to SU.  What OS are you using?  What is the size limit you are trying to achieve?  What have you tried already? What are the acceptable file types?   Have you checked questions such as [Highest compression for files(for web transfer)?](http://superuser.com/questions/6912/highest-compression-for-filesfor-web-transfer), or perhaps [How can I achieve the best, standard ZIP compression?](http://superuser.com/questions/154927/how-can-i-achieve-the-best-standard-zip-compression)?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following archivers, check which one suits you best. It depends on the file.

- [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)
- UHARC ([WinUHA](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/WinUHA.shtml) or [UHARC GUI](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/UHARC-GUI-by-Brhack.shtml))
- [KGB Archiver](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/KGB-Archiver.shtml)

These clients are for Windows, but I think you can get the equivalent on *UNIX machines as well.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the file you want to compress and then from the menu click sent to from then click compressed zip folder. then you can rename your folder if you want or e-mail it at a reduced size